# How to pass mouse events to a WinForms control at design time?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, mouseevent, design-time

We have a custom-made WinForms grid control which inherits the standard Control class. Users can create columns at design time using our custom verbs and the interactive column collection editor, but they cannot resize the created columns interactively at design time using normal mouse actions (similar to column resizing in the Windows Explorer).

To allow that - i.e. passing all mouse input to the grid header when the mouse pointer is over its area, we overrode the GetHitTest method of the designer attached to our control (inherits ControlDesigner). Structurally it looks like the following one:

```
protected override bool GetHitTest(System.Drawing.Point point)
{
  if (IsMouseInGridHeaderArea())
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

All works almost as expected while we are just moving the mouse pointer: the column headers are correctly highlighted at design time as the user is moving the mouse over them, and the mouse pointer is changed to the double-arrow WE-resize cursor when it is over the column divider area. The only minor problem for the latter case is that the cursor is constantly changed back to the 4-arrow cursor which indicates that the whole control can be selected/moved (the standard behavior for all controls on a form in the WinForms form designer).

When we hold down the left mouse button when column resizing can be performed, nothing happens. Even the whole grid control isn't moved on the form.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: @JoeKorolewicz, why did you add the c# tag? The question isn't related to C# only, it is about the general WinForms designer functionality. I can remove that C# code snippet without changing the meaning of the question, or rewrite it with VB.NET. It's just a structural example of what we have I used C# for.

Comment: I understand that this question could just as easily be VB.NET. But I added the tag because there is C# code in the example.  Adding that tag will broaden the amount of people who will see the question.  If you don't feel as if it should be tagged that way, you're more than welcome to remove it.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?